# WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted event not working properly

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am trying to call sub or function to extract URL from web page when web page is completely loaded.

```
 Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

        If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString = URL1 Then

URLCode(WebBrowser1.Document.Links(21).OuterHtml)

        End If

End Sub
```

Where

```
Private Function URLCode(ByVal STR1 As String) As String

    Dim STRLen = Len(STR1)
    Dim IndexKod = STR1.IndexOf("quick-view/") + 12
    Dim STR2 As String = Strings.Mid(STR1, IndexKod, STRLen)
    URLCode = STR2.Substring(0, STR2.IndexOf(""""))

End Function
```

So the problem is that function is started before page is completely loaded. Also when I put `msgbox` before function, everything is working fine. I've tried some available solutions for this problems but nothing helps.

Is there a way to know when the page is fully loaded without this event?

**EDIT 1 :**

Part of the HTML code

```
  <TR class="dx-row dx-data-row dx-row-alt ">
    <TD title=" " colspan="16">
      <DIV title=" " class="row">
      <DIV class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <DIV class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <H5 class="text-medium text-lg notranslate"><A href="/company/quick-view/aadty-aawty">COMPANY NAME</A>                                 <IMG class="country-flag-small" 
      src="/Assets/admin/content/flags/rs.png">                             
      </H5></DIV>
```

Element in question taken form Firefox

```
<a href="/company/quick-view/aadty-aawty" title="COMPANY NAME">COMPANY NAME</a>
```

`URLCode(WebBrowser1.Document.Links(21).OuterHtml)` should extract this part : **aadty-aawty**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `DocumentCompleted` also fires when the page has loaded for instance an `<iframe>`, you can check the [**`ReadyState` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.readystate(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine if the page is fully loaded.

Then, to find your element if it's added after the page load I'd add a timer that continuously looks if it exists or not, matching the beginning of the link.

```
Dim WithEvents URLTimer As New Timer With {.Interval = 250}

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    If WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
        URLTimer.Start()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub URLTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles URLTimer.Tick
    For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Links
        Dim href As String = Element.GetAttribute("href")
        If href IsNot Nothing AndAlso href.StartsWith("/company/quick-view/") Then
            URLTimer.Stop()

            Dim Value As String = href.Remove(0, "/company/quick-view/".Length)
            MsgBox(Value)

            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The `Value` variable inside the loop contains the text after `/company/quick-view/`. I made it read from the parsed HTML element rather than the string representation of it, thus you no longer need the `URLCode()` function.

**NOTE:** Since the `DocumentCompleted` event is still attached, currently the timer will be started again if you navigate to a different page. If this isn't what you want please tell me how you need it to work and I can fix that as well.

Comment: Still, function is fired before web page fully loaded, with or without WebBrowser1.Url.ToString() = URL1. Also, Msgbox before URLCode will fix this problem here too.

Comment: @Jovica : That isn't possible. The `If` statement checks if the page is fully downloaded and rendered by the browser, otherwise it doesn't pass. Do note that this doesn't (and never will) take Javascript into account, which might add elements after the page has loaded. If adding a delay (like a `MsgBox`) works then this is most likely what happens.

Comment: @Jovica : Please show me the HTML code of the element you want to get, and also some of the code surrounding it.

Comment: When button is clicked, it generates URL1 (strings combined), and URL1 is then opened via webbrowser. After web page opens there is URL within web (URLCode(WebBrowser1.Document.Links(21).OuterHtml). DocumentCompleted event will give URLCode from page before the click. Firing URLCode function with msgbox or independently via another button will give proper result.

Comment: @Jovica : Got that. I edited my comment a few times, please re-read it.

Comment: So, it's not possible to include Javascript somehow? HTML code doesn't include WebBrowser1.Document.Links(21).OuterHtml result. It is extracted with WebBrowser1.Document.Links(21).OuterHtml. BTW, My knowledge of HTML is very limited.

Comment: @Jovica : It's not possible without polling (actively looking for it every `x` seconds/milliseconds). -- And the HTML _**does**_ include that, otherwise you wouldn't be getting it from your code. Print the value of `WebBrowser1.DocumentText` when you press a button after the page has loaded, then you should see the element. Now take only a part of that HTML and put in your question and I should be able to help you.

Comment: @Jovica : Alternatively, if the element still isn't present in `DocumentText`, put the result of `WebBrowser1.Document.Links(21).OuterHtml` in your question.

Comment: Thanks. Timer fixed the problem.

Comment: @Jovica : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!